# PHP Handler for my LAMP server

Tags: web-server, server, php

I have a Pi4 4GB and i am using a Samsung Fit USB 3.0 32GB as Hard Drive.

I have set up a LAMP Server and i would like to know what handler will work better?

Apache 2.0 or PHP-FPM 7.3? or any other suggestions.

I will use my server for my web app which is 10pages created with bootstrap and contain datatables.
I am loading in some pages big sql queries.